# Rail postgres array contains (<@) dont include nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Matchups table that includes a field that is equipment_id and stores an array

I am trying to search the Matchups table to get any records that have an array where it contains specific equipment ids. For example: 
So I am running:

```
search_equipment_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Matchup.where("equipment_id <@ ARRAY[?]", search_equipment_ids)
```

The following are a few examples of arrays that are stored in the table in equipment_id and what the above query would result in

```
[1, 2] = True
[3, 5] = True
[1, 2, 3] = True
[1, 2, nil, 3] = False
```

How can get the search to ignore that there might be a nil included in the array. I am going to make a change to how the array is stored so from here on out there will be no nil values...but in the mean time I need to take these into account.

I am using: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html as a reference.

I dont want to use the && operator because the Matchups table is huge it will return to many results if just comparing if one equipment id is present. I want to only return if all the equipment_ids are contained (excluding any nils).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the `nil` values from the array? That's easy:

```
Matchup.where(..., equipment_ids.compact)
```

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, the search var (equipment_ids) is not the one that has the nil value. The equipment_id field in the table holds the nil value.

Comment: Just modified the question to hopefully provide some clarification

Comment: You should probably get rid of those by updating each record and expunging them.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am working on now...but there are 3000+ rows...just trying to see if there was an easier way :)

Comment: The easier way is keeping your data clean and not having to clutter up your code with hacks to deal with the mess. 3K rows is nothing. If it was 3B I'd understand your hesitation.